# Jquery mouseover mouseout issue for a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a menu show on hover of a header on this website.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$("#header").mouseover(function() {
    $('#header_links').stop(true, true).show(400);
});

$("#header").mouseout(function() {
    $('#header_links').stop(true, true).hide(400);
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
  <div id="header_title">leks kamihira&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="header_links">
  <a href="work.php">works</a>
  <a href="bio.php">bio</a>
  <a href="blog">blog</a>
  <a href="links.php">links</a>
  <?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) { ?>
  <a href="admin">admin</a> 
  <a href="admin/logout.php">logout</a>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, whenever the `header_title` div or `header_links` div is also hovered over, the `header_links` dissapear.

Is there a way to make sure that so long as the divs are contained inside the main header div, that the mouseover and mouseout function correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **[mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)** and **[mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)**:

```
$("#header").mouseenter(function() {
    $('#header_links').stop(true, true).show(400);
});

$("#header").mouseleave(function() {
    $('#header_links').stop(true, true).hide(400);
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pt7aX/)

[**Here's a nice simple demo**](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) showing the differences between `mouseover()` and `mouseenter()`.

---

You could also use this, as `@PSL` mentioned:

```
$("#header").on('mouseenter mouseleave',function() { 
   $('#header_links').stop(true, true).toggle(400); 
});
```